# Test closing and reopening the browser with jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

In some cases I have locally set session cookies that are supposed to vanish when the browser is closed and reopened, and in other cases I have persistent cookies.

These cookies are set dynamically according to application logic.  I'd like write to tests for them, but that requires the ability to automate closing and reopening the browser.

To clarify, the test needs to

1. invoke the code that sets the cookies
2. close and reopen browser
3. verify assertions about whether the cookies are still set or not
4. report the results.

How can I do this with Jasmine?

Comment: Can you delete the cookies and refresh the page?

Comment: No, then it wouldn't be an automated test.  The test needs to 1) invoke the code that sets the cookies 2) close and reopen browser 3) verify assertions about whether the cookies are still set or not 4) report the results.  I don't see how it could be done with the browser test runner, but figured there might be a way with jasmine's CI capabilities which use phantomJS